# Inserting data from a txt file into a database

Tags: python

Im trying to insert all lines from a txt file, in the format name:age seperately into the database.

This is what I have tried:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES (%s, %s)")
```

Txt file:

```
Adam:23
Olivia:19
Mark:45
Robert:34
Markus:23
```

Please help me to figure this out, or at least give me a hint, Im new to programming.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: If you could help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
agefile = open("text.txt", "r")


sql = "INSERT INTO test (nick, ip) VALUES (%s, %s)"

for row in agefile:
    data = row.split(':')
    val = (data[0], data[1])
    mycursor.execute(sql, val)

agefile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! it works, but when I check it in the database its contains '\n' at the end ('1.1.1.1\n',)

Comment: @NataliaBrzowinska To remove `\n` at the end in code instead of `data[1]` use `data[1].rstrip()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, you just need to insert the `value tuple` in the query.

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES (%s, %s)" %tuple(row.split(':'))
```

Or,

it will be even better if you separate your query from the data

```py
query = "INSERT INTO test (name, age) VALUES (%s, %s)"
with open('test.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        mycursor.execute(query, %tuple(row.split(':'))
```